# AJAX Links Not Detected By A:Visited

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, jquery-mobile, browser-history

I'm noticing that `a:visited` styles don't work on links that are requested via JavaScript. On a standard user click though, the exact same link registers as visited, both immediately and on subsequent refreshes. I'm not sure if this is unique to [jQuery Mobile](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/ajax-links-not-detected-by-a-visited) (where I first encountered it) or whether it's a browser limitation that I didn't know about?

Comment: Could you show us the code? I'm guessing that the fault could be in "return false" in the event. Because of the return false, default actions are prevented, and it's not registered like you have actually visited the link.

Comment: Any standard <a href="page.htm" /> in the jQuery Mobile context exhibits this - you can check out the demo site and insert a:visited style there to see the behavior: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a3/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to change the location.hash if you want it to work with history and visited links styling.

Keep in mind that the visited links styling works somewhat inconsistently between browser after the visited links based browsing history privacy vulnerability was made popular by [Did You Watch Porn](http://didyouwatchporn.com/) website.

Comment: I know the selector for a:visited was removed from CSS3 but the classic behavior should still be there. And yes, the location.hash is changed (back and forward navigation works fine). See the demo link above.

Answer (score 2):

`a:visited` matches any link that points to a URL that is in the browser history.

If you use AJAX to cancel navigation to the URL, the URL will never end up in the browser history.

You can fix that by using `#` links.

Comment: Thanks, but please see the demo link above.

Answer (score 1):

`a:visited` is only triggered if the link is 'executed'.

A link to an AJAX call usually returns 'false' (The solution with a hash (`<a href="#">link</a>`) still returns false otherwise the user would jump to top of page).

That way the link is never being 'executed', therefore not being marked as visited.

Comment: Thanks. Seems a bit strange to me but I think you're right. I mean the browser does make a request to that page and does have a copy in its cache on subsequent visits to that page... intuitively, this qualifies as a visit.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, please don't change `a` element's `href` to point to a hashed url like the other answerers are saying - that will break the user experience. If they want to open in new window it will then need to double load, if you do the change server-side it will break search engines and js-disabled users.

The issue is that if you are using hashes to upgrade your website into a RIA (rich internet application) then the links will point to `mysite.com/page` but you actually access `mysite.com/#/page` so you don't actually visit the original.

The proper solution here is to use the HTML5 History API, which allows you to change the URL directly and hook into URL changes (so there is no longer a need for hashes). You can read more about the pros and cons of hashes vs hashbangs vs HTML5 History API here:
https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/wiki/Intelligent-State-Handling - it also includes sample code to upgrade your website with the HTML5 History API too.

jQuery Mobile is scheduled to use to the HTML5 History API in the future (it's currently being worked on), but for now I'd suggest waiting it this is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

You can always set a class on the link via the ajax callback that shares the style with a:visited.