# CSS a:visited Not Working with AJAX Call - Ruby On Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a Ruby on Rails application in which I am tracking likes or dislikes on various topics. When a user hits like, the number of likes increases and the number is displayed immediately via an ajax call to reload a partial. But the issue is since the link_to calls a function in one of my controllers which then executes the ajax (in respond_to), nothing is actually ever stored in the history, so the links can't change color on visited.

Here is my css:

```
/* Links */
a:link {
  color: #06c;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
  color: red !important;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover{
  color:#D8CA92;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:active {
  color: #CC9966;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

my link:

```
<%= link_to '&#9650;'.html_safe,{ :controller => :confessions, :action => :upvote, :id => conf.id }, :remote=>true %>
```

And the associated js.erb file that gets called

```
$('#ajax').html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'layouts/confessions') %>");
```

How can I get the a:visited to work while still using the ajax call?

Comment: Maybe you can add a `class` manually using `addClass('visited')` if it's not visited instead of using `a:visited` after you click the link.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278305/ajax-links-not-detected-by-avisited

Comment: Looking at the above question, I still have the same issue.

Comment: Do you know how I can pass the link click onto the associated js.erb page? I can do `$("a").addClass("visited");` but that changes every link.

Answer (score 2):

As Sheikh commented the easiest way to do that is to add `.visited` class to links (the only other way would be to use html5 api which as you might imagine is not supported that widely). The way you do it is to setup callback after successful rails ajax calls:

```
$(function() {
  $('a').on('ajax:success', function() {
    $(this).addClass('visited');
  });
)};
```

You may want to use live instead if those links can be added through ajax calls. Note that this will not preserve state between clicks. To do that you would probably need to save states into cookies or something like that.